# Products disappeared in wordpress with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I have a multi site wordpress, with (among other sites), two ecommerce with woocommerce: they have the same theme and are the italian and german version. One week ago, I update the italian version to the same theme as the german, but suddenly yesterday products in the italian website disappeared, also in the admin (while they're still present, because categories still count them). I re-inserted them but today they disappeared again, what could it be? I really have no Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well answer is no, Woocommerce will not work on multisite, nor for now. In fact what you are doing (having two sites instaled separately) can be done from one single wp and woo instalation and instaling a translation plugin like WPML, then you will have both languages (or many more), in just one wp, no multisite required.

http://wpml.org/

Also you can take a look on some ideas related to your question:

http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/2502035-woocommerce-multi-site-shopping-cart-feature

Comment: I already have 2 eccomerce with woocommerce installed in my multisite wp network and they worked correctly, until I added the third one. I don't need them to be connected, just 3 separated ecoomerce, is that possible?

Comment: But, how you have those 2 woocommerce instaled on the multisite network? For what i know, is not able already to run on mu. Do you have diferent domains or sites are on subdomains? You have only one woocommerce folder on server? Do you have it selected as "available for all sites" on network admin? or you installed it from each site back end?

Comment: I installed it from each site back end